# Crystal Reports print labels based on query count

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a dataset and I need to loop through the records and print a crystal reports label based on how many pallets I'll have.

So in this instance I need the first record set to print 9 times the second to print 5 times, the next to print 4 then 12 for the last.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: At least one of the 3rd-party desktop Crystal reports schedulers (ses list [here][1]) provides an option to print copies governed by a Crystal formula.

Option 2: if you can create a "REPEATER" table with a single column (How_Many) containing a row for each value: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6...
In your report, add the REPEATER table and add a join condition of
Pallets_Quantity >= Repeater.How_Many
If the ">=" join option is not available, remove the join to the REPEATER table and create this condition in the Record Selection formula:
{Pallets_Quantity} >= {Repeater.How_Many}

This would cause each order to be duplicated as many times as the value of {Order.quantity}.

Option 3: if the quantity is fairly small, you could create cloned sections as Detail b, Detail c, etc. and control which ones are suppressed based on the quantity.

[1]: https://%20at:%20https://kenhamady.com/productlinks/default.html#desktopsched)